# ORA-00911: invalid character while creating before insert trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have created a below trigger for **Before Insert** with the below code

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER TR_UPDATE_FR_LOGTYPE
    BEFORE INSERT
ON LOGSAPDEALSLIPFUNDREQINTGRTN
    REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW  
    BEGIN
      IF (:NEW.RESPONSESTRING IN ('Record already exists') and  :NEW.LOGTYPE='ServiceFault') THEN
              :NEW.LOGTYPE :='Success';  
       END IF;  

         IF (:NEW.RESPONSESTRING is null and  :NEW.LOGTYPE is null and :NEW.STATUS is null) THEN
              :NEW.STATUS :='T';
         END IF;
          IF (:NEW.RESPONSESTRING <> null and  :NEW.LOGTYPE='Other') THEN
             :NEW.STATUS :='S';
         END IF;
         IF (:NEW.RESPONSESTRING <> null and  :NEW.LOGTYPE is null and :NEW.STATUS is null) THEN
         :NEW.STATUS :='S';
          END IF; 
END TR_UPDATE_FR_LOGTYPE;
END
```

But getting error as

> ora 09111 invalid character

Comment: This: ':NEW.RESPONSESTRING <> null' looks wrong - to check for NULL values, use `IS NULL` resp. `IS NOT NULL` (just like you did in the other clauses).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the last END has to be simply removed:

```
/* Formatted on 28/02/2017 11:13:38 (QP5 v5.136.908.31019) */
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_UPDATE_FR_LOGTYPE
   BEFORE INSERT
   ON LOGSAPDEALSLIPFUNDREQINTGRTN
   REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF (:NEW.RESPONSESTRING IN ('Record already exists')
       AND:NEW.LOGTYPE = 'ServiceFault')
   THEN
      :NEW.LOGTYPE := 'Success';
   END IF;

   IF (    :NEW.RESPONSESTRING IS NULL
       AND:NEW.LOGTYPE IS NULL
       AND:NEW.STATUS IS NULL)
   THEN
      :NEW.STATUS := 'T';
   END IF;

   IF (:NEW.RESPONSESTRING IS NOT NULL AND :NEW.LOGTYPE = 'Other')
   THEN
      :NEW.STATUS := 'S';
   END IF;

   IF (    :NEW.RESPONSESTRING IS NOT NULL
       AND:NEW.LOGTYPE IS NULL
       AND:NEW.STATUS IS NULL)
   THEN
      :NEW.STATUS := 'S';
   END IF;
END TR_UPDATE_FR_LOGTYPE;
```

Comment: Can I use like this `IF (:NEW.RESPONSESTRING LIKE '%Record already exists%'`  Instead of `:NEW.RESPONSESTRING IN ('Record already exists')`

Comment: Yes, you can, if RESPONSESTRING is VARCHAR2 type.  Moreover, pay attention that RESPONSESTRING is case sensitive as all VARCHAR2.

Comment: <> NULL always fails!  Use IS NOT NULL instead.

Comment: btw the brackets around all the `if` conditions aren't needed, because PL/SQL  has a `then` keyword.

Comment: You already have a correct answer. I was just saving you some typing in future because there is no need for brackets around `if` conditions, and the ones you have aren't doing anything and will just be ignored. Also `REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD` does nothing, and you don't need to code in uppercase.

Comment: Thanks @UltraCommit

Comment: Glad I could help ;-)

Comment: hi, are you thier ??

Comment: I am over the internet ;-)